# for-loop to log moving files with date

Tags: bash, logging, for-loop

Basically what i want is this but in a for-loop..

```
echo `date +'['%H':'%M':'%S']'` - `mv -vf test* test/` > log.txt
```

This works as i want except that it print everything on a single line. I want it to make a new line and a date stamp for every file moved.

Right now i get:

```
[10:12:36] - "test1.txt" -> "test/test1.txt" "test2.txt" -> "test/test2.txt" "test.txt" -> "test/test.txt"
```

But want:

```
[10:12:36] - "test.txt" -> "test/test.txt" 
[10:12:37] - "test1.txt" -> "test/test1.txt"
[10:12:38] - "test2.txt" -> "test/test2.txt"
```

I guess i will need a for-loop to solve this but have not been able to figure it out. I also do not want to use variables as i want it on a single line. But that might not be possible?

Correct answer provided by Mat was:

```
for i in `mv -vf test* test/` ; do echo `date +'['%H':'%M':'%S']'` - $i ; done > log.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
IFS='
'; set -f
for i in `mv -vf test* test/` ; do echo `date +'['%H':'%M':'%S']'` - $i ; done
```

Comment: Yes! It worked.. thaks! Didn't need IFS='' though.. and had to add the "> log.txt". So it looked like this..
for i in `mv -vf test* test/` ; do echo `date +'['%H':'%M':'%S']'` - $i ; done > log.txt

Comment: @AlMehdi: Yes, you do need the `IFS` part. Without it, your script will choke horribly if you have a file name containing whilespace. You also need `set -f`, for file names containing globbing characters.

Comment: @Gilles: It is not for a script.. i just wanted to make a log on files i move. And it worked without the "IFS" part. But thanks anyway.. it is good to know.